# Несколько ответов callback API VK

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть вот такой код, который должен спамить в ЛС цифрами от 0 до 19.

```html
<?php
$token = 'dsds'

function SendMass ($massnge, $userId) 
{
  $request_params = array(
    'message' => $massnge,
    'user_id' => $userId,
    'access_token' => $token,
    'v' => '5.85'
  );
  $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
       file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?' . $get_params);
}
    
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$userId = $data->object->from_id;

 echo ('ok');

for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
{
  getSendMass($i, $userId);
  sleep(1);
}

?>
```

Код выполняется 20 секунд, из-за чего Callback API не успевает получить ответ 'ok' и из-за этого бот спамит 2 раза вместо одного.

Как можно отправить 'ok' еще до выполнения скрипта. Пробовал flush(), но это не помогает.

Comment: в смысле два раза?

Comment: @Naumov Callback API если не получает ответа, отправляет запрос на сервер еще раз и из-за этого скрипт выполняется повторно.

Comment: ну так проверку поставьте если `success` значит ok если нет значит нет

Comment: Запускайте спамящий код в отдельном процессе, а этот процесс пусть сразу отправляет ok, не дожидаясь никаких 20 секунд, и тут же завершается (но как это грамотно делать с php, я не знаю)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно закрыть соединение, это делается следующим образом:

```php
<?php
header("Connection: close");
ob_start();

// Здесь у нас вывод чего-либо

$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush();
flush();
//Ваш код, который будет продолжать выполнятся
echo "Этого уже никто не увидит";
```

То есть, нужно исправить код так:

```
function SendMass ($massnge, $userId) {
    $request_params = array(
        'message' => $massnge,
        'user_id' => $userId,
        'access_token' => $token,
        'v' => '5.85'
    );
    $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
    file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?' . $get_params);
}

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$userId = $data->object->from_id;


header("Connection: close");
ob_start();

echo ('ok');

$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush();
flush();



for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++){
    getSendMass($i, $userId);
    sleep(1);
}

?>
```

Кстати, я бы на вашем месте вынес токен в константу.

Answer (score 0):

Принятый ответ не совсем работал у меня. Проблему решила одна строчка `ob_end_clean();`

Таким образом код должен быть таким:

```
<?php
function SendMass ($massnge, $userId) {
    $request_params = array(
        'message' => $massnge,
        'user_id' => $userId,
        'access_token' => $token,
        'v' => '5.85'
    );
    $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
    file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?' . $get_params);
}

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$userId = $data->object->from_id;

ob_end_clean(); // Без неё не работает
header("Connection: close");
ob_start();

echo ('ok');

$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush();
flush();

for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++){
    getSendMass($i, $userId);
    sleep(1);
}
```